# Using an undirected graph to represent an ordered pair?

Tags: graphs, trees, graph-traversal

Set theory depends on a set membership function $\epsilon$ which is a class of ordered pairs.  Is it possible to construct *the ordered pair* from an undirected graph of *unordered pairs*?  Alternatively, is there a way to construct a undirected graph that represents a directed graph?

The graph may be traversed from either a start node or optionally any node.  I realize most theories on graph depend on set theory and I am considering the case where set theory depends on this structure of graph theory for its ordered pair.  I'm interested because the undirected graph appears more basic then directed, as no order is required.

I was thinking of the following undirected graph for ordered pairs, where the vertices are points and edges lines.  The start node is at the top.  The structure of order can be distinguished by the two subgraphs at depth 4.  The leaves > depth 4 represent an ordered value which depends on the depth of that member of the pair.

[image]
Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "construct the ordered pair from an undirected graph of unordered pairs"?  I'm having difficulty understanding what you are asking.  What is the definition of "represents a directed graph"?  There are countably infinitely many directed graphs, and countably infinitely many undirected graphs, so there is certainly a bijection between them.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4448946/14578

Comment: @D.W. re: represents a directed graph, I mean the undirected graph has structure of the order of the pairs in the directed graph, such that there is an inverse back again.  Re: the ordered pair, I would like an undirected graph representation that can be used to represent an ordered pair.